# Ionic Android build under Linux issue

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic under Debian and been struggling to compile to android for days now. I've installed android sdk like the following:

```
sudo apt-get install android-sdk
```

I tried to compile like the following:

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

It trows this error

*Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.*

The problem is, that there's not an skdmanager binary nor Android binary to accept them!. It's driving me crazy, any ideas on how to solve it? Thank you in advance.

I solved it by downloading sdk separately, using that binary to accept the licences and then copied them to /usr/lib/android-sdk/licences/
I'm still confused about the missing binaries so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue faced by many developers. You need to locate the SDK manager file.

If it is globally set then just open the terminal and run below command:

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

If not then first find the sdkmanager file  which is usually under:

```
/Users/YOUR_MAC_USER/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
```

On MacBooks. and then run the same above command `./sdkmanager --licenses`. It will resolve your problem.

**Note**: `./sdkmanager --licenses` will prompt you through each licenses you haven't accepted yet and you can just enter y to accept each of them.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that installing via apt the binaries inside /sdk/tools/bin did not contain sdkmanager nor android. I had to download sdk separately to have access to them. I'm sure I'm missing something. Thanks for your time.